# Simple parser using Flex and C++

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, c++17

This is an alternative parser based on the specifications from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/246219/parser-written-in-php-is-5-6x-faster-than-the-same-c-program-in-a-similar-test).  Briefly stated, the input file is a text file which has at least 33 fields separated by semicolons.

If the fourth field begins with either a `T` or an `E`, the line is valid and a subset of it written to the output file.  Specifically, fields as numbered from \$0\$, should be output in this order: \$ \{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 11, 7, 32\}\$, each separated by a comma.  All other fields are discarded.

One of the other answers there suggested that one could use a [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator))-based parser instead. My own efforts were not faster, but I'm hoping that someone can review this and show me how to extract more speed from this version.

## lexer.l

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <iterator>
#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int FileLexer::yylex()


class FileLexer : public yyFlexLexer {
public:
    FileLexer(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) :
        yyFlexLexer{&in, &out},
        out{out}
    {}
    using FlexLexer::yylex;
    /// the yylex function is automatically created by Flex.
    virtual int yylex();
private:
    /// pointer to the current value
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::ostream& out;
    unsigned fieldcount{0};
    bool valid{true};
};


%}
%option warn nodefault batch noyywrap c++
%option yyclass="FileLexer"

FIELD  [^;\n]*
DELIM   ;
%%

{DELIM} { }
\n      {
            if (valid && fieldcount >= 33) {
                std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(out, ","));
                out << '\n';
            }
            vec.clear();
            fieldcount = 0;
            valid = true;
            return 1;
        }
{FIELD} {
            if (valid) {
                switch (fieldcount++) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 9:
                    case 32:
                        vec.push_back(yytext);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (yytext[0] == 'E' || yytext[0] == 'T') {
                            vec.push_back(yytext);
                            valid = true;
                        } else {
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        {
                            auto n{vec.size()};
                            vec.push_back(yytext);
                            std::iter_swap(vec.begin()+n, vec.begin()+n-2);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        {
                            auto n{vec.size()};
                            vec.push_back(yytext);
                            std::iter_swap(vec.begin()+n, vec.begin()+n-1);
                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc >= 3) {
        std::ifstream in{argv[1]};
        std::ofstream out{argv[2]};
        FileLexer lexer{in, out};
        while (lexer.yylex() != 0)
        {}
    }
}
```

Compile with:

```
flex -o parsefile.cpp lexer.l
g++ -O2 -std=gnu++17 parsefile.cpp -o parsefile
```

This works, but it is slow (2.165 s) on my machine, with the same million-line input file as mentioned in [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/246219/parser-written-in-php-is-5-6x-faster-than-the-same-c-program-in-a-similar-test/246270#246270) to the other question.

I tried it a few different ways, but I was unable to get a version that was faster than the PHP code in the other question.  The `switch` statement logic is arguably a bit overly clever and stores only the needed fields in the desired order, but the speed was about the same as the straightforward implementation.

If it matters, I'm using `gcc` version 10.1 and `flex` 2.6.4 on a 64-bit Linux machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few small issues in the C++ code, that probably won't give any large performance benefit. Flex is doing the heavy work of reading the input and parsing it, there's not much you can do about that.

## Iterator arithmetic

Instead of:

```
case 10:
    {
        auto n{vec.size()};
        vec.push_back(yytext);
        std::iter_swap(vec.begin() + n, vec.begin() + n - 2);
    }
```

You can also do iterator arithmetic on the end iterator, thereby avoiding the need to get the size of the vector:

```
case 10:
    vec.push_back(yytext);
    std::iter_swap(vec.end() - 1, vec.end() - 3);
```

## Don't `return 1` after reading a newline character

There is no need to return from `yylex()` after reading a newline, just remove the `return 1` statement. This avoids needing the `while`-loop in `main()`.

## Use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`

This avoids having to create a temporary that is being copied into the vector.

Comment: Strangely, I found that if I eliminate the `return 1;` the program runs very slightly slower.  I don't know why, but it is repeatable.

Comment: @Edward That's very weird... looking at the generated `parsefile.cpp`, I don't see any reason why it would be faster; there's initialization at the top of `yylex()`, but it's only executed the first time it is called. Maybe the difference is down to the alignment of the generated machine code.

Comment: Do you see the same timing effect?

Comment: I don't see any difference in timing with any of the changes I mentioned, it's all in the noise.

Comment: @Edward Can you confirm this is still the case at `-O3`? That might just cause it.

Comment: My apologies!  It was pilot error.  There is a small difference, but much more logically, it's the non-`return` version you suggested which is faster.  The difference, with `-O3`, averages 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

### Overview

<strike>There is an issue (**Bug**) here in that `yytext` points at the beginning of the lexeme. But the lexeme is not null ('\0') terminated. You need to pass a length if you want to pass the current token into `vec`</strike>

```
   vec.push_back(yytext);

   // should be:
   vec.emplace_back(yytext, yytext + yylen);
```

---

You had a bug in your call to the underlying base class.

```
    FileLexer(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) :
        yyFlexLexer{&in, &out},
        out{out}
    {}
```

Sorry I fixed it before any answers. But you need to pass the address of the streams to `yyFlexLexer`.

---

Normally I would return a value for each lexeme (and move any complex processing into methods of `FileLexer`. **BUT** this is such a simple class I don't see any issue with your current implementation of putting all the code in the lexer directly (though I would remove the `return 1;` from the end of line marker to make it consistent with field processing).

---

This seems to be correct.

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(out, ","));
out << '\n';
```

But it is not obvious how it achieves it. Would be nice to have a comment that points out that field 10/11 are not added to the end but rather to a point not at the end of the end of the vector.

---

Comment: I think you may be mistaken about `yytext`.  In [this part](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory.html#A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory) of the manual, it notes that if you want to preserve `yytext`, you should use `strdup` which expects a `'\0'`-terminated string.

Comment: Also, since 2015, the version of the constructor which requires pointers is deprecated in favor of a reference version.  See line 1534 of [this patch](https://github.com/westes/flex/commit/336a1deaa57975f34cd732d656d1c0cbe3d5233a#diff-d7ef57bcc5501f4ad873f97c94d4f759R1534).

Comment: Man software keeps getting better. The current version on my mac requires pointers  So this looks like we need some autotools rule to check the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for helping me make *my* software better.