# Produce the sum of all white space separated integers in a given file

Tags: c++, stream

How's my code?  Works perfectly for what I'm trying to do :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<assert.h>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }



int main() {
    int sum{ 0 }, number;
    vector<int> numbers;
    string word;
    fstream file;
    file.open("file1.txt", fstream::in);

    while (true) {
        file >> number;
        if (file.eof()) {
            numbers.push_back(number);
            break;
        }
        else if (file.fail()) { 
            file.clear();
            file >> word;
        }
        else if (file.bad()) exit(1);
        else numbers.push_back(number);
    }

    for (int x : numbers) sum += x;

    cout << sum << "\n";


}
```

Here's the file I'm reading from:

```
words 32 jd: 5 alkj 3 12 fjkl: 23 / 32
hey 332 2 jk 23 k 23 ksdl 3
32 kjd 3 klj 332 c 32
```

Comment: You say "sum of all white space separated integers" and that your code "Works perfect". Does it really? Because if the file contained for example `foo 332bar baz`, you'd use the `332` even though it's not separated from `bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You collect all numbers but then use the collection only for the sum. Better just update the sum. And I find the whole trying int and if fails use word a bit complicated. How about just always reading words and then reading numbers from them? (The `>>` writes zero if there's no number.)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    ifstream file("file1.txt");
    string word;
    while (file >> word) {
        int number;
        istringstream(word) >> number;
        sum += number;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<assert.h>
```

This would be easier to read with some spaces between `#include` and the header name.

`<assert.h>` is a C standard library header file. C++ supplies its own version of the C headers which put their content into the `std` namespace, and we should use that version instead. These headers have `c` added to the front, and no extension, e.g. `#include <cassert>`.

It's nice to arrange includes in alphabetical order.

Note also that we don't need all these headers - include only what you need.

---

```
using namespace std;
```

This is a bad habit to get into. It can lead to name collisions for large projects. It's best to avoid it and type the namespace where you need to (e.g. `std::vector`).

---

```
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }
```

This function isn't used! If you're using visual studio (or the microsoft compilers in general), you can set the linker subsystem to `CONSOLE`, which keeps the console window open after the program finishes running.

---

```
int sum{ 0 }, number;
vector<int> numbers;
string word;
```

Variables should be declared as close to the point of use as possible:

- We don't need `sum` until much later.
- `number` can be declared inside the loop.
- `numbers` is only needed after we've opened the file (just before the loop).
- `word` isn't needed until an inner scope of the loop.

Variables should not be reused (unless there is a significant performance hit - e.g. allocating large objects in memory), as it makes it harder to spot mistakes.

---

```
fstream file;
file.open("file1.txt", fstream::in);
```

We can use the `fstream` constructor to open the file, instead of opening the file in a separate step.

We could use `ifstream`, since we're only interested in file input.

---

```
while (true) {
    file >> number;
    if (file.eof()) {
        numbers.push_back(number);
        break;
    }
    else if (file.fail()) { 
        file.clear();
        file >> word;
    }
    else if (file.bad()) exit(1);
    else numbers.push_back(number);
}
```

There's nothing wrong with `while (true)`. It's often much clearer than trying to cram lots of logic into the loop condition.

There's also nothing wrong with multiple exit points, or `return` statements. We should `return` (or `break` or `continue`) as soon as possible in our code to simplify the logic and avoid unnecessary branching and nesting.

There are a couple of things we can simplify here:

- We should only have one point where we add a number to the vector (duplicate code is harder to maintain).
- If we exit the loop with `break` or `return` (or start a new loop iteration with `continue`), we don't need to use an `else if` because the `else` is implicit. We can just use a separate `if` statement.

There's also a subtle bug here. [When the `bad` bit on a stream is set, the `fail()` function also returns `true`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/bad)! So instead of `exit()`ing, we'll try to clear the (unrecoverable) error, the `bad` bit will be set again, and we end up in an infinite loop. So we need to check `bad()` before we check `fail()`.

---

It would be nice to print some error messages to `std::cerr` if something goes wrong (the file doesn't open, or reading from it fails).

It would be nice to have a comment or two where the purpose of the code isn't immediately clear (e.g. what `word` is used for).

---

Applying this we might end up with the following:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    
    std::string filename = "file1.txt";
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "failed to open file: " << filename << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<int> numbers;
    
    while (true) {
        
        int number;
        file >> number;
        
        if (file.bad()) {
            std::cerr << "unrecoverable error while reading from file: " << filename << "\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        
        if (file.fail()) {
            // input was not an integer! 
            // clear the error, and discard input until the next whitespace
            file.clear();
            std::string word;
            file >> word;
            continue;
        }
        
        numbers.push_back(number);
        
        if (file.eof()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : numbers) sum += x;
    
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Comment: *"There's also nothing wrong with multiple exit points, or return statements! We should return (or break or continue) as soon as possible in our code to simplify the logic and avoid unnecessary branching and nesting."* **Re** I find the statements contradictory. Multiple exit points introduce branching which you say is unnecessary! //  "*Contrary to what the other answer says, there's nothing wrong with while (true)! It's often much clearer than trying to cram lots of logic into the loop condition.*"  **Re** If the design is good, the cramming can be reduced to just function calls.

Comment: 1. Consider the code above, and try to rewrite it using a single `return` at the end of `main()` and you'll see what I mean. You'll probably end up with extra `else` branches, and a ternary statement to figure out what value to return at the end.

Comment: 2. Sure, sometimes. But you can do lots of things in the loop body that you can't do in the loop condition (e.g. declare and use variables). If it's anything other than a simple function call, I'd suggest it's better to put it in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer with less complex while loop and no use of `stringstream`s.

I've found `std::stoi`/`std::stof` faster than `>>` operator to convert strings to numbers. Also, we have a clear indication of failure in the form of exceptions.

---

If you only need the sum, don't store all numbers. If the file is big, it's just memory waste.

---

```
#include<cmath>
#include<assert.h>
```

Unused headers.

- https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    std::ifstream file_s("file1.txt");
    if (file_s.bad()) {
      return -1;
    }

    std::string word;
    while (std::getline(file_s, word, ' ')) {
        try {
           sum += std::stoi(word);
        }
        catch(const std::invalid_argument& ex) {
            std::cout << ex.what() << ":" << word << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you get the correct sum for their example? Your code [gives me 857](https://repl.it/repls/GreedyThoseBlogware#main.cpp) instead of the correct 889.

Comment: Ah thanks! Your file contains newline which the question doesn't specify: only space-separated words.

Comment: You can see the newlines if you open the question editor. They're there, the OP just didn't make them visible (sigh).

Comment: Oh. Then to use `std::stoi` one should split a line (read by `std::getline` + `'\n'`) using the splitter written here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/247292/205955 // There's no need to store words as `std::string_view`s either but they're cheap, so its fine.

Comment: How about `sum += std::stoi(word);`?